# How to add data locally in many columns?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

someone can help me here ? How do I add data locally in many columns ?
I have tried but...

Below my code,
I tried to create more var like : "var salary = document.forms.MedList.salary.value; var test = document.forms.MedList.test.value; 
localStorage.setItem(name, data, salary, test);
" etc, but It does not work...

I have to change my doShowAll function or something like this ?

```
function SaveItem() {

var name = document.forms.MedList.name.value;
var data = document.forms.MedList.data.value;
localStorage.setItem(name, data);
doShowAll();
```

}

```
function doShowAll() {
if (CheckBrowser()) {
    var key = "";
    var list = "<tr><th>Nome</th><th>Estoque</th></tr>\n";
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
        key = localStorage.key(i);
        list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>"
                + localStorage.getItem(key) + "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    if (list == "<tr><th>Nome</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n") {
        list += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list;
} else {
    alert('Cannot store Med list as your browser do not support local storage');
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean 'many columns'? Local storage is key value pairs. You can have anything as the value, it's usually best to create an object, do a json stringify on it and store that.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do but like @Magrangs said, Localstorage is just key value pairs.  If you need to store multiple values in one key, put them inside an array and loop through them.  Also, you can't loop through localStorage like that, as it's not an array.  You'd want to do something like `for (var key in localStorage)` which loops through an object and it's keys.

Comment: Example
Column1:    Column2:  Column3:   Colunm4:
Datex          Datex1      -----            ------
Can't I do this with local storage ?

Comment: Brett84c Yeah, I want to store multiple values... How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create an object and store that e.g.

```
var myObject = {
 name: document.forms.MedList.name.value,
 data: document.forms.MedList.data.value
}

localStorage.setItem("yourKey", JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

When you want to grab it out you can do:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourKey"));
```

and then access the name and data respectively:

```
myObject.name
myObject.data
```

If you wanted to store multiple values under one key, the value can be an array:

e.g.

```
var myObject = {
 name: document.forms.MedList.name.value,
 data: document.forms.MedList.data.value
}

var myObject2 = {
 name: document.forms.MedList2.name.value,
 data: document.forms.MedList2.data.value
}

localStorage.setItem("yourKey", JSON.stringify([myObject, myObject2]));
```

Comment: Think of local storage like a dictionary. You can have anything as the value, an array if you like

Comment: I get it.. I think haha, but I'm triyng here and does not work in my code... How do I use many keys inside for ?